# Opencart error message

Tags: php, error-handling, e-commerce, opencart

I have installed opencart on `www.completeofficechairs.co.uk`.

and youll notice I get the error message:

```
    Fatal error: Call to a member function isLogged() on a non-object in 
     /var/websites/completeofficechairs/www/admin/controller/common/header.php 
on line 101
```

I cant work out whats wrong. If I go to the file, the line of code in question is:

```
  if (!$this->user->isLogged() || !isset($this->request->get['token']) 
|| !isset($this->session->data['token']) 
|| ($this->request->get['token'] != $this->session->data['token'])) {
                $this->data['logged'] = '';
```

However, the admin side of the store is working.

This is confusing and annoying. Hoping someone can help.

Comment: what version of opencart are you on? and does this error come up all the time?

Comment: im on v 1.5.1.3 and yes if you go to completeofficechairs.co.uk it comes up everytime, but I can still access admin area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

by the looks of the error, you have the wrong config file for the catalog side of things. It's loading up the admin on the home page, which is why that object doesn't exist (or vice versa)

Comment: I had not realized that both files, `/config.php` and `/admin/config.php` are different. Admin side wasn't working. I installed locally a new store and then upload `config.php` files to corresponding folders.